# Is there a way to programmatically point the cursor at a specific word?

Tags: c#, console

I currently have a console application that I'm using via the command line with a file .The given file now becomes a huge string .This string is split into an array of words.
This array is searched with foreach for my search term. my question is now how to solve the problem that the focus is placed directly on the first word found and this word is selected.

```
var splittedTxt = text.Split(' ');

        if (decisionForWholeWords == true && decisionForSpelling == false)
        {
            foreach (var item in splittedTxt)
            {
                if (wordToFind.ToLower() == item.ToLower())
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

                    wordFound = true;
                }
                Console.Write(item);
                if (wordFound) // reset color
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

                    wordFound = false;
                }
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cursor with a method:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
```

Or by using the left and top properties:

```
Console.CursorLeft = x;
Console.CursorTop = y;
```

You'll have to figure out the position of your word and set the cursor to that position.

Comment: The problem is that I split the text into an array and now each word is in it individually.
How am I supposed to find out the position now, in theory I only have the array where there is always a word in it?

Comment: This depends on how you display the words; if you print each word out on a new line, you can use a for loop instead of a foreach loop. The index your word is at will be the height your cursor has to be at.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (decisionForWholeWords == true && decisionForSpelling == false)
{
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in splittedTxt)
        {
            //do what you want the index.
            if (wordToFind.ToLower() == item.ToLower())
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

                wordFound = true;
            }
            Console.Write(item);
            if (wordFound) // reset color
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

                wordFound = false;
            }
            Console.Write(" ");

            index += item.Length;
            index += 1; //for the space
        }
    }
```